# Overlay button on image - Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, css

I am having real difficulty overlaying my button in the bottom right corner of an image in lightning. My code is like so:

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="AMEXCOMMHomePageController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"  access="global">
<ltng:require styles="{!join(',', 
                        $Resource.SLDS213 + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}"
              scripts="{!join(',',
                        $Resource.AMEXCommunityResource  + '/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')}"
              />
<div class="background">

    <img src="{!$Resource.AMEXCOMM_LandingBannerImg}"/>


            <button class="btn-refer" onclick="{!c.gotoNewApp}">Refer Your Client Now</button>

    </div>

</aura:component>
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS .btn-refer {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.THIS .background {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    width: 998px;
    height: 248px;
    margin-left: 17px;
}
```

**Image**

[image: Button slid over to the left. Needs to be overlayed]

EDITT

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your current page?

Comment: @MartinLezer added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
   .THIS .btn-refer {
       right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.THIS.background {
    position: absolute;

}
.THIS img {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
.THIS .btn-refer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}

.THIS .background {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    width: 998px;
    height: 248px;
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.THIS .background img{
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The position relative on your background container allows us to position the btn-refer inside the container depending on its size.

Comment: That has just pushed the button even further to the right, off the image :/

Comment: This is because your image doesn't fit the whole container. Do you want the image to take the whole width of its container?

Comment: Yeah that would be best

Comment: Ok I edited my answer. This should work. If the button is too much on the right you can increase the value of the "right: 20px;" until it's good for you.

Comment: Ive edited the original post to show you what its looking like now

Comment: Ok I edited my answer again. As you can see in your capture, the image is not filling its container. Whereas the button is on the right of the same container. This is why the button is not overlaying the image.

Comment: No change i think the issue is stemming from the .btn-refer

Comment: Are you familiar with Google Chrome dev tools? Can you inspect the size of the image and the size of the div with the class "background"?

Comment: @nebbyyy your button is to overley over image on right bottom corner is it right???

Comment: @vignesh correct

Comment: Did you checked with below code CSS

Comment: Yes technically it works but when i add in the overlay for my button it doesnt

Comment: @Nebbyyy OK .I working out wait